# How to display fixed Text over a 360 Panorama Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, 360-panorama

I am displaying a 360 panorama image with the following code, using the aframe library:

```
  <a-assets>
    <img id="sky" crossorigin src="../HomePage.jpg">
  </a-assets>
  <a-scene>
    <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
    <a-entity position="0 2 -5">
      <a-text value="Welcome to My Website" align="center" color="#fff" width="6"></a-text>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

This code displays the text "Welcome to My Website" over the 360 image, however, it rotates with the image when users rotate it while I would like the text to remain fix. How can I achieve this? Thanks.